# Java FX Menu background color bug?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-css

So I am having a small problem which is pretty weird. I have styled my menu and menu bar of my undecorated application. If I hover a menu item in the context menu the menu will change it's background color to the default one of windows.

Pictures of the scenario (in the second picture, I am hovering the 'Models' menu item):
[image: Here I am hovering a menu which is doing its job.]

[image: If I hover one of my menu items, the menu it's background jumps to blue.]

[image: If I am not standing on the menu item with my mouse, the menu item will also have a blue background.]

Does anyone knows how to fix the blue backgrounds? I want the menu to have my hover background like in the first picture. And the menu item should have its own background also and not jump to blue if I am not with my mouse on it.

CSS:

```
.menu-bar {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
.menu {
    -fx-label-padding: 3px;
}
.menu .label, .menu-item .label {
    -fx-text-fill: #eee;
}
.menu:hover, .menu:focused, .menu:pressed {
    -fx-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.menu-item:hover {
    -fx-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.context-menu {
    -fx-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this to your css

```
.menu-item:focused {
   -fx-background-color : <preferred color>;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you are adding redundant layers of properties to `.menu`and `menu-item`. Trying taking care of the concerned properties only. For example in your case `menu` needs to follow your coloring pattern when either `hovered` or in `showing` event.
So add

```
.menu:hover, .menu:showing{
  -fx-background-color: <preferred backgound>;
}
```

Similarly add only `focused` property to `menu-item`, because the rest it shares the `context-menu` backgound

```
.menu-item:focused{
  -fx-background-color: <preferred background>;
}
```

Look at the snapshot of the simple demo:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
.menu {
    -fx-background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.menu .label {
    -fx-text-fill: black;
    -fx-font-family: verdana;
    -fx-font-size: 11.5px;
}

.menu:hover,
.menu:showing {
    -fx-background-color: #CCE8FF;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}

.menu-item {
    -fx-background-color: #F2F2F2;
    -fx-text-fill: #000000;
    -fx-font-family: verdana;
    -fx-font-size: 11.4px;
}

.menu-item .label {
    -fx-text-fill: #000000;
    -fx-font-family: verdana;
}

.menu-item:focused .label {
    -fx-text-fill: #000000;
    -fx-font-family: verdana;
}

.menu-item:focused {
    -fx-background: -fx-accent;
    -fx-background-color: #91C9F7;
    -fx-text-fill: #000000;
    -fx-font-family: verdana;
}

.menu-item:disabled {
    -fx-background: -fx-accent;
    -fx-text-fill: #000000;
    -fx-opacity: 0.9;
    -fx-font-family: verdana;
}

.menu-item:focused:disabled {
    -fx-background: -fx-accent;
    -fx-background-color: lightgray;
    -fx-text-fill: #000000;
    -fx-font-family: verdana;
    -fx-opacity: 0.9;
}
```